# flask development server gives TypeError: environment can only contain strings

Tags: python, flask, pipenv

for my flask application i am using python-dotenv to load environment variable as below

```
from flask import Flask
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import pprint

load_dotenv('.env_original')
print os.getenv('SQL_USER')
print '**************'
pprint.pprint(dict(os.environ))
print '**************'

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'hello'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

but i got below error:

```
ate
**************
{'ALLUSERSPROFILE': 'C:\\ProgramData',
 'APPDATA': 'C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\AppData\\Roaming',
 'CHOCOLATEYINSTALL': 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey',
 'CHOCOLATEYLASTPATHUPDATE': 'Tue Jun 26 11:40:13 2018',
 'CHOCOLATEYTOOLSLOCATION': 'C:\\tools',
 'COMMONPROGRAMFILES': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files',
 'COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86)': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files',
 'COMMONPROGRAMW6432': 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files',
 'COMPUTERNAME': '0217RDNAB73',
 'COMSPEC': 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe',
 'DRIVERDATA': 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\Drivers\\DriverData',
 'HOMEDRIVE': 'C:',
 'HOMEPATH': '\\Users\\xxxxx',
 'KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK': 'TRUE',
 'LOCALAPPDATA': 'C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\AppData\\Local',
 'LOGONSERVER': '\\\\KIRBY',
 'MKL_SERIAL': 'YES',
 'NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS': '4',
 'ONEDRIVE': 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\OneDrive',
 'OS': 'Windows_NT',
 'PATH': 'C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\.virtualenvs\\fabric-49Df8aha\\Scripts;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\iCLS\\;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\iCLS\\;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32;C:\\WINDOWS;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\Client Access\\Emulator;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\Client Access\\Shared;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IBM\\Client Access\\;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\DAL;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\DAL;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\IPT;C:\\Program Files\\Intel\\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\\IPT;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd;C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\bin;;C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\OpenSSH\\;C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft VS Code\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\MPV;C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm;C:\\Python27;C:\\Python27\\Scripts;C:\\cygwin64\\bin;C:\\tools\\cmder;C:\\cygwin64\\usr\\local\\bin;C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\bin;C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\.virtualenvs\\fabric-49Df8aha\\Lib\\site-packages\\pywin32_system32;C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\.virtualenvs\\fabric-49Df8aha\\lib\\site-packages\\pywin32_system32',
 'PATHEXT': '.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC',
 'PIP_PYTHON_PATH': 'c:\\python27\\python.exe',
 'PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE': 'x86',
 'PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432': 'AMD64',
 'PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER': 'Intel64 Family 6 Model 94 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel',
 'PROCESSOR_LEVEL': '6',
 'PROCESSOR_REVISION': '5e03',
 'PROGRAMDATA': 'C:\\ProgramData',
 'PROGRAMFILES': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)',
 'PROGRAMFILES(X86)': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)',
 'PROGRAMW6432': 'C:\\Program Files',
 'PROMPT': '$P$G',
 'PSMODULEPATH': 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsPowerShell\\Modules;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Modules',
 'PUBLIC': 'C:\\Users\\Public',
 'PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE': '1',
 'SESSIONNAME': 'Console',
 u'SQL_USER': u'ate',
 'SYSTEMDRIVE': 'C:',
 'SYSTEMROOT': 'C:\\WINDOWS',
 'TEMP': 'C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp',
 'TMP': 'C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\AppData\\Local\\Temp',
 'USERDNSDOMAIN': 'xxxxx.xxx.xx',
 'USERDOMAIN': 'xxxxx_xxxxx',
 'USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE': 'xxxxx_xxxxx',
 'USERNAME': 'xxxxx',
 'USERPROFILE': 'C:\\Users\\xxxxx',
 'WINDIR': 'C:\\WINDOWS'}
**************
 * Serving Flask app "test" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: Do not use the development server in a production environment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Restarting with stat
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 38, in <module>
    app.run(debug=True)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\.virtualenvs\fabric-49Df8aha\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 943, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\.virtualenvs\fabric-49Df8aha\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 812, in run_simple
    reloader_type)
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\.virtualenvs\fabric-49Df8aha\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\_reloader.py", line 275, in run_with_reloader
    sys.exit(reloader.restart_with_reloader())
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\.virtualenvs\fabric-49Df8aha\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\_reloader.py", line 132, in restart_with_reloader
    close_fds=False)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 168, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "c:\python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "c:\python27\Lib\subprocess.py", line 640, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
TypeError: environment can only contain strings
```

Mu .env_original looks like below:

```
SQL_USER=ate
```

i am using pipenv virtual environment. any idea why it would have happen?

EDIT: added pprint dict output to os.environ. I have to hide few details with xxxx but those were string. env variable get loaded as unicode.

Comment: Can you print the `os.environ` mapping and check what value this is complaining about? `import pprint, os` then `pprint.pprint(os.environ)`, after running `load_dotenv()`.

Comment: hey i have updated my code, and as you can see, env get loaded as unicode

Comment: Ah, the `os.environ` object is a custom `dict` subclass, so `pprint(dict(os.environ))` would have been a lot more readable.

Comment: See https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv/issues/88, this appears to have been fixed in a newer version.

Comment: i have updated my code. and yes i am using latest version of it as well. 
python-dotenv==0.9.1

Comment: right, the update I see was for [pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/commit/82bf57a72908e1ea77b518a6af6a2342088bdfe5). That they patched their vendored copy makes me wonder why the python-dotenv project doesn't just fix this directly.

Comment: aah.. i see what you mean! that clear up few thing. if i rename .env_original to .env, pipenv take the bullet and my server runs fine. but since i am moving with encrypted dot file i need to have actual package handling task for me and that point it get fails.

Comment: You can tell Pipenv to load a different filename with `PIPENV_DOTENV_LOCATION`.

Comment: yeah but my dotenv is encrypted with cryptography. and i have to decode first based on who access that file. so i was passing decrypted content to load_dotenv as a stream.

Comment: You can import the patched version from pipenv then. `from pipenv.vendor.dotenv import load_dotenv`.

Comment: yeah kind of. i am using pipenv, so i have to install pipenv inside pipenv and then import the module. :D kind of funny but yeah that way i can have patched dotenv.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178947/discussion-between-d-s-and-martijn-pieters).

Answer (score 0):

As @Martijn Pieters points out, it's bug from python-dotenv side and pipenv have patched that one over here,
https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv/pull/101

using package from pipenv solves the issue.

```
from flask import Flask
from pipenv.vendor.dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
import pprint

load_dotenv('.env_original')
pprint.pprint(dict(os.environ))

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'hi'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```